# Run several commands together, finish if one of them exits?

Tags: linux, shell, monitoring

I have several commands that I run continuously during development of my website - Django development server, SCSS->CSS compiler in "watch" mode and so on. I want to have a convenient command to run them all together, stop them when necessary, and inspect the output in console (e.g. access logs, debug prints) while I develop and run my application.

How do I do that so that when one of them crashes, the whole command exits?

I was thinking about something like [multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) or tmux, but I'm still missing the monitoring and killing part. Should I write something myself, or is there already a good solution for my use case?

I'm using Linux (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set -e` to accomplish this in a shell script. When it is used, it causes the script to abort if any command returns a non-0 exit status. There are some nuances to it, though. More info can be found here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
echo this will print
cat -z this is a malformed command which will return non-0
echo this will not print
```

Output:

```
$ bash /tmp/test.sh 
this will print
cat: invalid option -- 'z'
Try 'cat --help' for more information.

$
```

Answer (score 0):

What about puting all your command on a shell script then use 'set -e' . this will exit your script as soon as you got a return code different than 0.

Answer (score 0):

In a bash script you can run several processes in the background (with `&`), and wait for any one of them to exit
with `wait -n`. You can also `trap` sigint from a keyboard <kbd>ctrl-c</kbd> and use it to
kill the processes. This example runs 2 sleep commands and when one ends kills the other.
If you keyboard interrupt the script, it kills both sleeps.

```
#!/bin/bash
myexit(){
    kill -1 $pids
    exit $rc
} 
pids= rc=1
trap myexit 1 2

sleep 5 &
pids="$pids $!"
sleep 10 &
pids="$pids $!"

wait -n
rc=$?
myexit
```